# Why when I change or try to add another different class of input does total sum stop working?

Tags: javascript, jquery

If I try and change an input class to something other then val1 or val2 the gandTotal stops working? Any ideas why this is?

I want to change the 1st and 3rd field and add an if statement like

```
if ( $val1 <= 20 ) { $total = 0 } else { $total =$val1 * 1 ) * ($val2 * 1)-10);}
```

an [example](http://www.vestedutility.com.au/ec/inc/testcal.php)

```
       <table>

        <tr class="calcrow no1">
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2" value="0.5"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow no2">
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2" value="49.5"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow  no3">
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2" value="20"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="calcrow no4">
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val1"  />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input name="txtEmmail" class="val2" value="49.5"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                    <span class="multTotal">0.00</span>
            </td>
        </tr>

            <tr>
    <td colspan="3" align="right">
        Grand Total#<span id="grandTotal">0.00</span>
    </td>
</tr>
    </table> 

 <script>   
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".calcrow  input").keyup(multInputs);

       function multInputs() {
           var mult = 0;
           // for each row:
           $(".calcrow ").each(function () {
               // get the values from this row:
               var $val1 = $('.val1', this).val();
               var $val2 = $('.val2', this).val();           
               var $total = ($val1 * 1) * ($val2 * 1)                                      
               $('.multTotal',this).text($total);
               mult += $total;
           });
           $("#grandTotal").text(mult);
       }

  });

  </script>
```

Comment: That's an invalid HTML Structure, so it never works. `<table>
  </tr>` is wrong.

Comment: Create a [MCVE] or the question gets closed.

Comment: Ive added a link to show the example

Comment: Okay... But the HTML is wrong. So it doesn't work.

Comment: ok i removed the </tr>, it was working with it though?

Comment: Why doesn't row `no1` and `no3` have a `"calcrow"` class?

Comment: because if i add the "calcrow" class and change the input class the grandtotal doesnt work?

Comment: Where are the input & row classes being changed in the code?

Comment: for example the 1st imput is class"sm8"

Comment: Yes, why do you have so many inconsistencies...

Comment: im not sure what you mean, so maybe the question should be how to i add an if statement ? to an a single input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, lets discuss naming conventions.

With jQuery, element names are usually prefixed with a "$", like this:

```
var $val1 = $('.val1');
```

Where as values, should not start with that same prefix

```
var val1 = $('.val1').val();
```

The reason I bring this up, is yes, you could name things however you want, but for other people to read and understand your code, following conventions makes it easier.

Next, if the value is to be manipulated, it should be converted into a numeric value. So the last statement above should become:

```
var val1 = parseFloat($('.val1').val() || 0);
```

The `|| 0` converts an empty string in the value to a zero.

Now a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) can be used to process the values as you wanted:

```
var total = val1 <= 20 ? 0 : (val1 * 1) * (val2 * 1) - 10;
```

Lastly, a `.toFixed(2)` is added to the text to truncate (not round off!) the visible values.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".calcrow  input").keyup(multInputs);

  function multInputs() {
    var mult = 0;
    // for each row:
    $(".calcrow ").each(function () {
      // get the values from this row:
      var val1 = parseFloat($('.val1', this).val() || 0);
      var val2 = parseFloat($('.val2', this).val() || 0);
      var total = val1 <= 20 ? 0 : (val1 * 1) * (val2 * 1) - 10;

      $('.multTotal, .sm8',this).text(total.toFixed(2));
      mult += total;
    });
    $("#grandTotal").text(mult.toFixed(2));
  }

});
```

I may not have understood all the requirements you are trying to meet, but try this demo here: http://jsbin.com/jeqiki/edit?html,output

Comment: thanks mottie for taking the time to explain a few things, much appreciated. Is it possible to apply the ternary operator to a selected out put? as the one you have shown i only want for output 1 and i want to create another for output 3 and leave 2 and 3 as they are?

Comment: Thank you for your help I was able to figure it out

Comment: not sure why but the .tofixed   on this line  $("#grandTotal").text(mult.toFixed(2));  doesn't work on chrome comes up with testcal.php:85 Uncaught TypeError: total.toFixed is not a function

Answer (score 0):

```
 <script>   
     $(document).ready(function () {
       $(".calcrow  input").keyup(multInputs);

       function multInputs() {
           var mult = 0;
           // for each row:
           $(".calcrow ").each(function () {
               // get the values from this row:
               var val1 = parseFloat($('.val1', this).val() || 0);
               var val2 = parseFloat($('.val2', this).val() || 0);
               var sm8 = parseFloat($('.sm8', this).val() || 0);     
               var vu = parseFloat($('.vu', this).val() || 0);     

                var total =  (val1 * 1) * (val2 * 1);

                var sm8T = sm8 <= 20 ? 0 : (sm8 * 1) * (val2 * 1)-10;     
                var vuT= vu <= 2 ? 0 : (vu * 1) * (val2 * 1)-40;

                $('.vuT',this).text(vuT);                                
               $('.sm8T',this).text(sm8T);
                $('.multTotal',this).text(total.toFixed(2));

               mult += sm8T+vuT+total;
           });
           $("#grandTotal").text(mult.toFixed(2));
       }

  });

  </script>
```